# 3D chart with Jfreechart

Tags: java, jfreechart, pie-chart

Is it possible to draw a 3D chart using JfreeChart like in the following link.If possible can anyone give some hints and some snippets of code on what parameters of Plot can be used to do this.

[link text](http://www.amcharts.com/pie/3d-donut-chart/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible though it won't look exactly the same. The easiest way is to create a dataset  (descendant of `org.jfree.data.general.PieDataset`) and use one of `org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory` methods:

```
PieDataset data = new DefaultPieDataset();
data.setValue("Section1", 30);
data.setValue("Section2", 60);
data.setValue("Section3", 120);
JFreeChart pieChart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(
 "My Pie Chart", // title
 data,           // data set
 true,           // draw a legend
 true,           // show tooltips over sections
 false);         // do not generate image map with URLs
```

You can then further customize your chart through `pieChart` methods. For example, here's how to explode one pie section:

```
 PiePlot plot = (PiePlot) pieChart.getPlot();
 plot.setExplodePercent("Section2", 0.25);
```

Comment: cool thanks...Can you suggest good color codes and ofcourse not colors..My bad I have a poor sense for colors

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "color codes and not colors"? As picking colors goes I'm no designer :-) but you can search SO for "chart colors" - there are quite a few questions / answers. I'd go with predefined palette rather than trying random stuff, though. Good luck with your project.